# "Salviamo la lingua italiana" : come definire il fenomeno dell'invasione dei termini stranieri

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Torna con forza l'idea che la lingua italiana sia in pericolo per l'eccessiva contaminazione da parte di termini stranieri, in particolare inglesi.

> - “[Salviamo](http://www.i-siena.it/2015/02/salviamo-la-lingua-italiana-dallinvasione-inglese-vola-la-petizione/) la lingua italiana dall’invasione inglese”. Vola la petizione
> - Nella petizione si legge: “Una petizione per invitare il governo italiano, le amministrazioni pubbliche, i media, le imprese a parlare un po’ di più, per favore, in italiano.

Ma qual è il termine più corretto per descrivere questo fenomeno? Imbastardimento della lingua, contaminazione o qualche altro?

P.S. Questa domanda è attiva anche [qui](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/233187/an-appropriate-term-for-the-contamination-of-a-language) e [qui](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/11643/what-is-a-proper-term-for-the-contamination-of-a-language).

Comment: Ho suggerito una modifica (non un edit) :) --- con questa formulazione e questo titolo, la tua mi sembra più una pubblicità per la petizione che non una domanda vera e propria.

Comment: Mi sembrava più pertinente il titolo alternativo proposto. Se la domanda riguarda il nome del fenomeno, che c'entra “Salviamo etc.”? Gio, hai visto la [discussione su Meta](http://meta.italian.stackexchange.com/questions/1291/clickbait-question-and-rejected-edit)?

Comment: @DaG - perché la mia domanda nasce da lì e la "petizione" è un aspetto importante di questo fenomeno. Citarla è corretto e doveroso. Se si ritiene che il tutto sia off-topic" allora I moderatori devono cancellare la mia domanda, non modificarla.

Comment: Infatti, citala nel testo della domanda, ma il titolo dev'essere più conciso possibile. Vedi anche la mia risposta su Meta.

Comment: Non capisco tutto questo trambusto per aver citato una petizione che ha a che fare al 100% con la lingua italiana e, in teoria, anche con questo sito.

Comment: Nessun trambusto per aver citato la petizione, @Gio! È che alcuni utenti di questo sito, tra cui la sottoscritta, sono piuttosto pignoli: cerchiamo che tutto sia sempre perfetto! E adesso ci troviamo a discutere: qual è il "titolo perfetto" per questa (più che degna) domanda?

Comment: @Charo - c'è qualche regola secondo la quale il mio titolo sia "inadatto"? Come ho già detto la petizione è di fatto il fulcro della domanda. La questione sta nel suo contenuto, ossia che la lingua italiana abbia   raggiunto un livello "di guardia" per quando riguarda l'uso di termini stranieri. Impostare la questione in termini generici fa perdere efficacia alla questione.  Se ritieni che tutto ciò sia soggettivo e quindi off-topic  per me va bene se cancellate il tutto, ma non che lo modificate.

Comment: La domanda non è affatto fuori tema: tutto il contrario! Quindi, non cancellarla, per carità! La domanda che fai sul titolo, penso sia meglio discuterla sul Meta, OK?

Comment: _come definire il fenomeno dell'invasione dei termini stranieri_ `Naturale evoluzione di una lingua come normale adattamento al contesto in cui viene usata`. Ai tempi dei miei nonni non si poteva dire "vado al bar", bisognava dire "vado al caffè" perché "bar" non era una parola italiana. Imporre queste cose dall'alto è un'attitudine a dir poco ingenua. Non funziona così. Non facciamoci del male cercando di opporci al naturale andamento delle cose.

Comment: @SantiBailors - la mia domanda non vuole entrare nel merito della questione ( argomento off-topic) ma semplicemente definire il fenomeno. Ogni considerazione sul merito è ovviamente personale.

Comment: Hai ragione, Gio. La mia definizione del fenomeno (definizione personale, ma probabilmente tanto quanto qualunque altra) secondo me va bene in riferimento alla tua domanda, ma è vero che il resto me lo potevo risparmiare. Errore mio, senza dubbio; ci starò più attento in futuro.

Answer (score 7):

Volendo essere più precisi e diretti, si potrebbe descrivere questo fenomeno semplicemente come un *abuso degli anglicismi nella lingua italiana*. Più chiaro di così.

*Imbastardimento* va bene, ma è un concetto molto ampio al quale si possono ascrivere, per esempio, gli influssi dialettali.

*Contaminazione* non mi sembra una buona scelta, perché ha anche una connotazione positiva: si parla infatti di *contaminazione culturale* come di un fenomeno che può portare a un arricchimento e che magari è bidirezionale. Siamo invece di fronte a un impoverimento culturale e a un abuso degli anglicismi che è soprattutto un fenomeno sociale. Risulta infatti difficile spiegare con la linguistica le ragioni di chi dice "scusa sono in *call*, ci sentiamo poi?" e personalmente faccio fatica a chiamare questo fenomeno "contaminazione". Credo che ad occuparsene debbano essere gli psicologi e i sociologi, non i linguisti.

Comment: Aggiungo solo che esiste una branca della linguistica che si occupa esattamente di questo tipo di problemi – e con l'approccio che suggerisce gd1 – che si chiama appunto sociolinguistica.

Comment: @DaG - e la sociolinguistica come definisce questo fenomeno?

Comment: Non ne so abbastanza, purtroppo, @Josh61. Immagino che oltre alla corretta e oggettiva definizione sull'abbondanza di anglicismi, un sociolinguista parlerebbe dell'influenza esercitata da una lingua o varietà considerata di maggior prestigio.

Comment: *Contaminazione non mi sembra una buona scelta, perché ha anche una connotazione positiva*: qui mi sembra proprio che tu stia confondendo l'appropriatezza del termine con la tua opinione personale. In sé "contaminazione" ha un significato più negativo che positivo, e inoltre una parola per indicare il concetto di "entrano termini stranieri nella lingua italiana" non deve implicare automaticamente un giudizio sul fatto.

Comment: Però questa risposta è incentrata su un giudizio di merito sul fenomeno (giudizio negativo), mentre (come ho appreso dalla giusta osservazione di @Gio in risposta a un mio commento affrettato alla sua domanda) considerazioni sul merito del fenomeno sarebbero off-topic. Le definizioni proposte in questa risposta sono apertamente il risultato della ricerca di una definizione che sia negativa.

Comment: Sono d'accordo con @FedericoPoloni sul fatto che difficilmente _contaminazione_ ha una connotazione positiva, in qualunque contesto venga usata. _Ci hai contaminati con le tue idee_ ha senz'altro una connotazione negativa, contrariamente a _ci ha contagiati con la sua allegria_.