# Quale verbo usare per parlare di un fatto che penso accadrà sicuramente in una situazione fittizia?

Tags: grammar, verbs, phrase-request, conditional-mood

L'altro giorno stavo cercando di scrivere qualcosa su un brano del libro *Dottor Niù. Corsivi diabolici per tragedie evitabili*, di Stefano Benni, che avevo letto di recente. Un aspetto di questo testo  che ha attirato la mia attenzione è la maniera di esprimersi (molte volte in modo indiretto attraverso le parole del narratore) "in italiano" del dottor Niù, il "consulente di aggiornamento tecnologico per famiglie", caratterizzata da un abuso di termini in inglese. Per [esempio](https://books.google.es/books?hl=it&id=ENbfCgAAQBAJ&q="new+profession"#v=snippet&q=%22new%20profession%22&f=false):

> Mi spiega che la sua è una new profession nata insieme alla new economy per una new way of life. Devo solo avere un old conto corrente con un po' di old fashion money per pagargli l'old onorary.

Ecco una frase che ho scritto per esprimere quello che penso che accadrà sicuramente nella situazione descritta nel libro:

> Nella società descritta nel testo, la "battaglia" per salvare la lingua italiana ***andava*** definitivamente persa.

(Questa frase fa parte di un mio testo in cui ho usato il presente per parlare di quello che accade nel libro.)

Prima avevo fatto riferimento alla campagna di cui si è parlato in [questo post](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/5201/salviamo-la-lingua-italiana). La frase mi è venuta così in modo spontaneo (forse perché, in registri colloquiali, gli italiani e anche i catalani tendono a usare spesso l'imperfetto al posto del condizionale?). Ma poi ho pensato che stavo descrivendo una situazione irreale (quella del romanzo), dunque dovrei usare il condizionale (periodo ipotetico dell'irrealtà) in questo modo:

> Nella società descritta nel testo, la "battaglia" per salvare la lingua italiana ***andrebbe*** definitivamente persa.

Ho ragionato che ciò che voglio esprimere sarebbe più o meno questo: *Se gli italiani parlassero come il dottor Niù, la "battaglia" per salvare la lingua italiana andrebbe definitivamente persa*. Quindi dovrei usare il condizionale invece dell'imperfetto. Beh, forse non è esattamente la stessa cosa perché nella frase parlo della società descritta nel libro (che è irreale anche perché tutta la facenda del dottor Niù è un incubo del narratore), e non della vera società italiana presente o futura.

Poi ho avuto il dubbio se il verbo "andare" fosse quello adatto perché, usato in modo idiomatico, tale verbo indica l'obbligo di fare qualcosa. Comunque, non è un obbligo quello che voglio esprimere,  ma un fatto che penso succederebbe di sicuro se si arrivasse a tale situazione. Quale verbo potrei usare al posto di "andare"?

Potreste aiutarmi a chiarire i miei dubbi? Come posso esprimere questa idea in modo corretto?

Comment: Non sono sicuro di capire compiutamente la tua domanda, ma spesso per riferire gli eventi di un testo, anche di fantasia, si usa il presente: “...e finalmente Frodo *arriva* al monte Fato” o anche, in un discorso più generale e costruito in modo più simile al tuo: “Nella Terra di Mezzo descritta da Tolkien, *sono* gli umili hobbit a salvare il mondo”. E se faccio ipotesi sul futuro posso usare appunto il futuro: “Ciò nonostante, un giorno l'oscurità *tornerà* a stendersi su Mordor”. Ma forse tu non stavi solo raccontando il libro, ma rapportandolo alla situazione reale?

Comment: Lascio lo scrivere una risposta a chi più competente, ma io userei senza dubbio l'imperfetto. Per me non si tratta di un periodo dell'irrealtà: una volta assunta la premessa dell'intero brano (cioè che viviamo nella società del dottor Niù), la frase è semplicemente descrittiva.

Comment: @DaG: Come hai visto, ho anche dei dubbi su quale tempo verbale usare per formulare la domanda: prima ho usato il futuro, dopo ho cambiato al condizionale e poi di nuovo al futuro!

Comment: @DaG: Non sto cercando di prevedere quello che accadrà nei capitoli successivi del romanzo, ma di sprimere una mia opinione su quello che penso possa sicuramente accadere se per la lingua italiana si arrivasse alla situazione descritta nel libro. E voglio essere ottimista e pensare che tale situazione non si corrisponda (ancora) con la realtà. Perlomeno gli italiani che scrivono su questo sito non si esprimono come il dottor Niù. ;)

Comment: @DenisNardin: Assumendo la tua premessa come vera (cioè che si tratti di una descrizione della situazione attuale della lingua italiana), **in un registro non colloquiale**, useresti davvero l'imperfetto? Non si dovrebbe usare il presente (la "battaglia" è ormai persa) o il futuro (la "battaglia" non è ancora persa, ma sarà definitivamente persa in un un futuro prossimo se non si fa niente per cambiare questa tendenza)?

Comment: @DenisNardin: Ecco quello che ho letto in un libro d'italiano per stranieri (livello avanzato): «Per il suo carattere di imperfettività l'imperfetto tende a essere sempre più usato nella lingua parlata per esprimere desideri, intenzionalità, ovvero fatti non situati nella realtà».

Comment: @Charo Ecco un esempio di una frase che io scriverei con l'imperfetto: *Nel 1788 la lunga battaglia per mantenere le finanze di Francia in attivo era ormai senza speranza e il regno precipitava verso l'insolvenza*. Per me non c'è nessuna connotazione colloquiale in questo ma non pretendo di essere un autorità. (Incidentalmente io direi che la battaglia *era* persa, non che *andava persa*).

Comment: @DenisNardin: Ma nel tuo esempio si sta parlando di fatti accaduti nel passato, cioè si tratta dell'uso standard dell'imperfetto. Io invece voglio fare riferimento a un possibile fatto futuro.

Comment: @DenisNardin: Forse dovrei dire semplicemente "sarebbe definitivamente persa".

Comment: @Charo Non credo che i commenti siano il posto giusto per continuare questa conversazione, ma ecco un altro esempio: *In Abissi d'Acciaio Asimov racconta di un futuro in cui l'umanità ha abbandonato l'esplorazione spaziale ed si è rifugiata in metropoli affollate*. Questa è una descrizione di un libro di fantascienza ambientato parecchi secoli nel futuro, ma io utilizzo tempi passati perché gli eventi che descrivo sono nel passato rispetto al momento della narrazione. Il *presente* non vuol dire necessariamente questo preciso momento, ma il contesto più generale in cui il brano è ambientato.

Comment: Mi sembra che stiamo parlando di varie cose un po' diverse fra loro e che nel complesso coprono buona parte di una trattazione della sintassi dei verbi: i tempi e modi appropriati per raccontare fatti storici, trame di libri, eventi ipotetici basati su fatti reali, eventi ipotetici basati su fatti ipotetici...

Comment: I bambini usano in modo naturale l'imperfetto in situazioni come “giochiamo che io ero un astronauta”. Da grandi quest'uso si perde. Direi *sarebbe persa*.

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR:** secondo me la confusione nasce da una frase impostata male in partenza. Personalmente riscriverei la seconda parte della frase in modo da evitare di finire in una situazione come questa.

Partendo da questa frase:

> Nella società descritta nel testo, la "battaglia" per salvare la
>   lingua italiana andava definitivamente persa.

Lettà così, senza contesto, questa frase significa che la battaglia per salvare la lingua italiana *va* persa (è necessario che vada persa), che non è il significato che vuoi trasmettere. Quindi direi che, così com'è, la frase non funziona per quello che intendi dire.

Questo mi porta alla seconda frase a cui hai pensato, quella in cui usi il condizionale. Qua c'è un po' di confusione secondo me, specialmente dopo aver letto il filo logico che hai seguito:

> Ma poi ho pensato che stavo descrivendo una situazione irreale (quella
>   del romanzo), dunque dovrei usare il condizionale (periodo ipotetico
>   dell'irrealtà)

Piccolo excursus: non confonderti tra irrealtà nel *tuo* mondo fisico e la realtà del romanzo. Solo perché un romanzo è opera di fantasia, non significa che tu debba per forza usare il condizionale. Quando parli di un'opera, quello è l'universo che ti trovi a dover analizzare. Dal punto di vista del mondo rappresentato nel romanzo, quello **è** il mondo reale.

Anche se, nel tuo esempio specifico, questa realtà esiste all'interno dell'incubo di uno dei personaggi, questo concetto continua a valere. Non prendere le regole per l'utilizzo del condizionale troppo alla lettera. Seguendo il tuo criterio, non dovresti usare il condizionale in moltissimi altri contesti dove invece viene usato anche in caso di assenza di situazioni irreali (se vuoi fare una richiesta in modo molto gentile, spesso si usa il condizionale - "Mi faresti un favore?").

Chiusa la parentesi condizionale (che, più che rappresentare situazioni irreali, viene usato se esiste una precondizione che, se soddisfatta, renderebbe vera la frase con il condizionale, ma evito di partire per la tangente), a questo punto tu dici:

> Comunque, non è un obbligo quello che voglio esprimere, ma un fatto
>   che penso succederebbe di sicuro se si arrivasse a tale situazione.

Se vuoi esprimere certezza, il tempo corretto nel tuo caso è il futuro:

> Nella società descritta nel testo, la "battaglia" per salvare la
>   lingua italiana verrà definitivamente persa.

Personalmente, soprattutto se decidi di mantenere l'inizio della frase così, io eviterei di usare questo formato, e scriverei qualcosa come

> Nella società descritta nel testo, non ci saranno speranze per la lingua italiana, destinata a scomparire definitivamente.

In questo modo eviteresti anche di dover usare le virgolette per l'utilizzo improprio del termine "battaglia".

Comment: Mi pare una risposta convincente. Comunque, se scrivo "verrà definitivamente persa" sto dicendo "sarà necessario che la battaglia si perda"? Potrei scrivere "sarà definitivamente persa"? Non saprei dire perché, ma questa ultima frase non mi suona bene: quella che hai proposto tu mi sembra molto meglio.

Comment: @Charo Sì, potresti anche scrivere "sarà definitivamente persa". Non stai trasmettendo intenzione in questo caso, stai semplicemente scegliendo un verbo ausiliare alternativo, puoi andare un po' a piacere (un po' come quello che succede nella forma passiva: puoi scegliere se scrivere "io sono mangiato" o "io vengo mangiato").

Comment: Ma "verrà definitivamente persa" significa "sarà necessario che la battaglia si perda"? Cioè, il significato è diverso di quello di "sarà definitivamente persa"?

Comment: @Charo No, il significato è lo stesso :) Entrambe le frasi significano "la battaglia sarà definitivamente persa". Usati in questa frase, "venire" ed "essere" sono sinonimi.

Comment: Hai ragione, si tratta dei diversi verbi ausiliari per formare la ***forma passiva***: ***essere***, ***venire*** o ***andare***.

Comment: Tuttavia, per rinfrescare la mia memoria, ho cercato la spiegazione sulla forma pasiva sul libro *Grammatica e pratica della lingua italiana per studenti stranieri* di Federica Colombo ed ecco quello che ho trovato: «**Andare** seguito da verbi come **perdere**, **distruggere**, **smarrire**, ecc. non assume il significato di **dovere** e si usa anche con i tempi composti.» Esempio: «***È andato distrutto*** il lavoro di una stagione. (È stato distrutto il lavoro di una stagione.)»

Comment: Quindi, siccome sto usando il verbo "perdere" nella forma passiva, potrei anche dire "la battaglia ***andrà*** definitivamente persa" senza intendere "sarà necessario che la battaglia si perda"? O questa forma passiva "andare" + "perso/a/i/e" che non significa "dovere" è soltanto per frasi come per esempio "è andata persa la mia valigia"?

Comment: Ma forse questo è un argomento interessante per porre un'altra domanda.

Comment: @Charo mmh, la domanda è interessante. In questo caso vedo la frase "È andato distrutto il lavoro di una stagione" come una frase al passato più che come una frase passiva, anche se formalmente ha la stessa struttura di una frase passiva.

Un chiarimento necessario: usare "è andato distrutto" *al passato* significa quello che hai detto tu, ovvero è sinonimo di "è stato distrutto", ma è una forma un po' più elegante. Quando usi "andare" (al presente o al futuro") + verbo, significa "è necessario/è buona cosa che questo venga fatto" (ad esempio: "va/andrà pulita la casa")

Comment: Usando sempre i tuoi esempi, se io dicessi "va distrutto il lavoro di una stagione" o "va persa la mia valigia" significa che è necessario distruggere il lavoro e perdere la mia valigia :D

Answer (score 0):

Ciao Charo!

Mi sembra più correto così:

> Nella società descritta nel testo, la "battaglia" per salvare la
>   lingua italiana **sarebbe** definitivamente persa.

PS: puoi dire sia **persa** che **perduta**

Comment: Puoi elaborare perché ritieni il condizionale corretto? A me suona molto stridente.

Comment: Ciao @Marcelo! Anch'io mi aspetto una risposta più argomentata.

Answer (score -1):

> Nella società descritta nel testo, la "battaglia" per salvare la
>   lingua italiana sarebbe **stata** definitivamente persa.

ciao

Comment: Guarda che si sta parlando di come esprimersi in italiano...

Comment: ho modificato la risposta, come puoi vedere

Comment: Sarebbe ***stata*** persa? Non è un po' troppo complicato?

Comment: Benvenuto/a su Italian.SE! Qui ci aspettiamo una risposta più argomentata.