# Forma passiva con l'ausiliare "andare": quando non significa "dovere"?

Tags: word-usage, grammar, auxiliary-verb

Ho letto la spiegazione sulla forma passiva sul libro *Grammatica e pratica della lingua italiana per studenti stranieri* di Federica Colombo, nella quale si indica che si può formare con diversi verbi ausiliari: ***essere***, ***venire*** o ***andare***.

Ecco l'informazione sull'ausiliare ***andare*** che appare in questo libro:

> **andare** + participio passato; **andare** si usa solo con i tempi semplici e solo alla 3a persona singolare o plurale. Il passivo con **andare** significa normalmente **dovere**: 
>   **Va mangiato** tutto! (Si deve mangiare tutto.) 
>  
>   **!**   **Andare** seguito da verbi come **perdere**, **distruggere**, **smarrire**, ecc. non assume il significato di **dovere** e si usa anche con i tempi composti. 
>   **È andato distrutto** il lavoro di una stagione. (È stato distrutto il lavoro di una stagione.)

Ho cercato di scrivere io stessa altre frasi passive con la costruzione ***andare*** + participio passato **nelle quali "andare" non significasse "dovere"**:

> - **È andata persa** la mia valigia.
> - I documenti **sono andati smarriti**.

Per poter capire meglio questo uso dell'ausiliare "andare", però, mi piacerebbe avere altri esempi. Me li potreste fare?

Se scrivo, ad esempio:

> la battaglia per salvare la lingua italiana **va definitivamente persa**

questa frase significa semplicemente "la battaglia per salvare la lingua italiana è definitivamente persa"? O il significato è piuttosto qualcosa come "è necessario che la battaglia per salvare la lingua italiana si perda" o "si deve perdere la battaglia per salvare la lingua italiana"?

Fa qualche differenza il fatto che il verbo "andare" sia al passato, al presente o al futuro (come suggerito in alcuni commenti a [questo post](https://italian.stackexchange.com/a/7603))? Cioè, se scrivo per esempio "la battaglia per salvare la lingua italiana **è andata** definitivamente persa" o "la battaglia per salvare la lingua italiana **andava** definitivamente persa" cambia il significato dell'ausiliare "andare"? E se dico "va distrutto il lavoro di una stagione" o "va persa la mia valigia" significa che si deve distruggere il lavoro e perdere la valigia?

Comment: In "la battaglia...va persa", il "va" suona come un imperativo per cui lo eviterei.." La battaglia può andare persa" o "andrà persa". Lo stesso problema si presenta nelle frasi finali dove il "va" può essere frainteso.

Comment: Non capisco il discorso dell'imperativo, @Gio. Intendi la seconda persona, “va'”, come se ci rivolgessimo direttamente alla battaglia?

Comment: Comunque, in effetti alcune di queste frasi sono ambigue, nel senso che sono corrette in entrambi i sensi. Il significato di una frase come “i documenti vanno distrutti” dipende dal contesto. In “L'ufficio va in fiamme, le persone scappano, i documenti vanno distrutti” vorrebbe dire che stanno bruciando; in “I documenti vanno distrutti prima che arrivi un controllo della polizia”, ovviamente significa che devono essere distrutti. Fuori contesto, probabilmente è questo secondo significato il più attivo.

Comment: @DaG - la battaglia va persa, il lavoro va distrutto, la mia valigia va persa...possono sembrare  espressioni dove il "va" suona come un imperativo.. Mi sembra che sia questo il dubbio di Charro.

Comment: Chiaro, @Gio, sono d'accordo.

Comment: Scusa, @Charo, ci dev'essere un refuso in “tempi compi composti”.

Comment: @DaG - si ma Charro solleva proprio questa possibile ambiguità nell'uso dell'indicativo.

Comment: @Gio: "Come un obbligo", no con il verbo in modo imperativo.

Comment: @DaG: Grazie, ho corretto.

Comment: Almeno quanto l'uso orale della lingua, questa forma non è molto comune. Il più usato è **"Ho perso la mia valigia"** oppure **"I documenti sono stati smarriti."**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Il verbo andare alla terza persona con il significato di dovere va usato solo se non c'è ambiguità nella frase.
Con i verbi perdere e distruggere il verbo andare può avere un altro significato, per cui è possibile una ambiguità, e bisogna fare attenzione.
Il verbo andare con significato di dovere si può usare al presente, al futuro o all'imperfetto, come in questi esempi:

- Questa lettera va distrutta subito, è compromettente.
- Questa partita andava persa, dovevamo aiutare gli avversari a vincere il campionato.
- Questo edificio andrà distrutto, non è possibile ristrutturarlo.

Il verbo andare con il significato di "essere" è invece evidente in questi esempi:

- Una lettera senza indirizzo andrà persa
- A causa della grandine, il raccolto va distrutto

Gli esempi della domanda sono volutamente ambigui, per cui è decisamente sconsigliato usare il verbo andare, ed è preferibile in quei casi usare forme più precise, che sono sempre possibili, anche se meno dirette. Gli esempi precedenti diventano:

- Questa lettera deve essere distrutta subito, è compromettente.
- Questa partita doveva essere persa, dovevamo aiutare gli avversari a vincere il campionato.
- Questo edificio dovrà essere distrutto, non è possibile ristrutturarlo.
- Una lettera senza indirizzo finirà con l'essere persa
- A causa della grandine, il raccolto finisce distrutto

Le frasi "va distrutto il lavoro di una stagione" o "va persa la mia valigia" possono essere più o meno ambigue in base al contesto, sta a chi scrive o parla capire quando è necessaria una forma che si presti meno ad essere fraintesa, anche se, fuori contesto, sembra più ragionevole interpretare il verbo andare nel senso di "finire" piuttosto che "dovere essere". 
Questo però solo perché è difficile immaginare contesti in cui sia necessario perdere una valigia o distruggere un lavoro.

Non c'è ambiguità invece quando si usano i tempi composti, dove il significato imperativo non è consentito. Non sono ambigue dunque le frasi: "è andato distrutto il lavoro di una stagione" o "è andata persa la mia valigia". Aggiungerei anche il caso del passato remoto, dove è molto difficile trovare applicazione del senso di dovere; "andò persa la mia valigia" va interpretato senz'altro come fatto accidentale e non voluto.

Comment: Quindi, con i verbi **perdere**, **distruggere**, **smarrire**, ecc. (veramente non so a quali verbi possa corrispondere questo "eccetera"), l'ausiliare **andare** può anche assumere il significato di **dovere**: dipende dal contesto e anche dal fatto che il tempo verbale sia composto o semplice.

Comment: Certo, va notato che il verbo smarrire indica implicitamente un atto involontario, per cui è difficile pensare un uso imperativo, del tipo "questa cosa va assolutamente smarrita entro domattina". Un altro verbo simile è disperdere.

Comment: Per esempio, "parte dell'energia **va dispersa** come calore" (non ha il significato di "dovere")?

Comment: Anche qui dipende dal contesto, se dico: "Dobbiamo aggiungere un dissipatore, perché parte dell'energia va dispersa come calore, altrimenti la temperatura sale troppo" il significato è di dovere. Se invece dico "non possiamo accumulare tutta l'energia, purtroppo parte dell'energia va dispersa come calore" il significato è diverso. Bisognerebbe però prevenire le ambiguità che inevitabilmente possono nascere in queste frasi, usando forme più esplicite.

Comment: Per fare un altro esempio, la frase "La battaglia per salvare la lingua italiana va definitivamente persa, se vogliamo vincere la guerra della lingua unica universale" intende il significato di dovere; invece se dico "Se continuiamo con questo atteggiamento esterofilo, la battaglia per salvare la lingua italiana va definitivamente persa, e prima o poi parleremo tutti inglese" il significato è diverso. Però in entrambi i casi lo stile e la chiarezza richiederebbero forme più esplicite.