# La campagna di cui si è ... "parlato" o "parlata"?

Tags: word-usage, grammar, pronouns, past-participle, agreement

Quando ho scritto questo [post](https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/7582) ho avuto il dubbio se dovessi scrivere "la campagna di cui si è parlato" oppure "la campagna di cui si è parlata". Cioè, come va fatto l'accordo del participio in una frase con il pronome relativo "cui" e con il "si" impersonale? Da questa [spiegazione dell'Accademia della Crusca](http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/it/lingua-italiana/consulenza-linguistica/domande-risposte/accordo-participio-passato) posso inferire che entrambe le alternative sono corrette? Se è così, una delle due opzioni è più usata dell'altra?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La questione dell'accordo con i participi è sempre spinosa (con una generale tendenza a perdere le concordanze, ma con diversi casi ed eccezioni), ma qui è piuttosto semplice: va bene il maschile.

Citando l'*Italiano* di Serianni (XI 364) sul tuo caso specifico, che non rientra in nessuno di quelli descritti in quella pagina della Crusca, si ha:

> Con un verbo impersonale o con un costrutto fondato sul «si passivante» ..., il participio è invariabile, nella forma del maschile singolare: «è *piovuto* per due ore»; «s'era *visto* di nuovo, o questa volta era parso di vedere, unte muraglie, porte d'edifizi pubblici, usci di case, martelli» (Manzoni, *I Promessi Sposi*, XXXII 7).

(Se hai questa grammatica del Serianni, i paragrafi dal 356 al 369 del cap. XI sono preziosi.)

Comment: Grazie mille, @DaG! Purtroppo non ho questo libro e qui non è facile trovarlo in biblioteca (penso ci sia un esemplare nella biblioteca della Facoltà di lettere della Università di Barcellona, ma non è così facilmente accessibile). :(

Comment: Considerando la serietà con cui prendi lo studio dell'italiano, @Charo, mi permetto di consigliarti di procurartelo: http://amzn.eu/9CVy06N (non prendo percentuali: magari!).

Comment: Tante grazie, @DaG, ci penserò (magari approfitto di qualche viaggio in Italia).

Comment: su Kindle si trova anche a meno, ma credo che si trovi completo anche su Google books